# How to properly return part of ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, sub-array

I have a class `SomeClass` with a static member `myMap` `enter code here`that has the form `HasmMap<String,ArrayList<SomeOtherClass>>` which gets de-serialized from a file.

I have a method

```
public ArrayList<SomeOtherClass> getList(final String key, final int N)
```

that is supposed to lookup `key` in the map and return the first `N` elements of the corresponding `ArrayList`, or the whole thing if the list has `<= N` elements. How should I implement the `TODO` line below:

```
public ArrayList<SomeOtherClass> getList(final String key, final int N)
{
    ArrayList<SomeOtherClass> arr = myMap.get(key);
    if (arr == null) return null;

    if (arr.size() <= N)
    {
       return arr;
    }
    else
    {
       // TODO: return first N elements
    }
}
```

to do it efficiently, i.e. without creating unneeded copies in memory while actually returning the right data?

Comment: There's a `subList` method. You can use it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Create a sublist with [`List`s `subList` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-).

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.
>
> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

Start at index 0 (inclusive start index), and end at index `N` (exclusive end index).

```
return arr.subList(0, N);
```

This does not copy the items to a new list; it returns a list view over the existing list.

Comment: I am getting `java.util.ArrayList$SubList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList`. I can replace `return arr.subList(0, N);` with `return new ArrayList<SomeOtherClass> arr.subList(0, N);` but then I would be creating a copy, right?

Comment: That's because the `List` returned by `subList` isn't an `ArrayList`.  You can have your method return a `List` instead of an `ArrayList`.  Alternatively, you can create an `ArrayList` from the sublist and return it, but that would involve copying.

Comment: @rgettman So it's not really that great a solution since he wanted an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Hasen Creating a new `ArrayList` would be inefficient because it involves copying object references to it.

Comment: @rgettman Inefficient or not, a `List` is not the same as an `ArrayList`, which is what was asked for.

Comment: @Hasen If you have a solution that can create the required `ArrayList` efficiently, without copying, then please post your answer.

Comment: @rgettman Yes I have a solution - you can't do it. Sometimes that's the correct answer. If you order some oranges from a supermarket, they don't give you potatoes instead, they just say they're out of stock.

Answer (score 5):

```
return arr.subList(0, N);
```

The documentation is your friend.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)